# How can I specify an optional field in an external struct using Kubernetes controller-gen?

Tags: kubernetes, kubebuilder

I am implementing a Kubernetes controller and am creating an API using a struct that looks like:

```
import (
    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
)

type MySpec struct {
    corev1.PodSpec `json:",inline"`
}
```

However, since the `Containers` field in `PodSpec` is required, when generating a corresponding CRD using [controller-gen](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-tools/tree/master/cmd/controller-gen) the `containers` field is being marked as required - however I want it to be optional in my CRD.

Is there any way to override this without copying out the whole structure or patching the output of controller-gen?

For reference the whole project is [here](https://github.com/dippynark/cluster-api-provider-kubernetes).

Comment: If your struct should be different, you must declare the fields

Comment: Just curious if you managed to achieve your goals?

Comment: @Nick unfortunately not, just patched the output of `controller-gen` in the most transferable way I could think of - was thinking of running it within a Docker container but thought against it

Comment: I also hope to override some filed to be optional or have a default value set. Have you found a solution? Thanks.

Comment: No I haven't unfortunately